# Update table with nearest value

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table with Postal Codes like this:

| Postal code | City |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | New York |
| 33101 | Miami |
| 94016 | San Francisco |

And another table, like this:

| Client | Postal code |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 33000 |

I need a query that updates the second table with the nearest postal code (from the first table). The result should be:

| Client | Postal code |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 33101 |

Comment: Please don't spam the database tags ... Edit the tags and pick the appropriate one

Comment: Would  32899 be closer ?  It is 101 away yet not over.

Comment: i removed the conflicting darabase tags

Comment: It should replace the value, with the closest one from the other table, either higher or lower.

Comment: can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
update Table2
set PostalCode = (
    select top 1 t1.PostalCode
    from Table1 t1
    /* optionally improve the lookup by requiring first two digits to match */
    where t1.PostalCode like left(Table2.PostalCode, 2) + '%'
    order by
        abs(cast(t1.PostalCode as int) - cast(Table2.PostalCode as int)),
        t1.PostalCode /* ties go low */
)
where not exists (
    select 1 from Table1 t1 where t1.PostalCode = Table2.PostalCode
)
```

This is generic SQL with these requirements: There's an absolute value function, that string concatenation is `+` (try `||` if not), that you have `top 1` or `limit 1` available, that postal codes are stored as strings that easily convert to integer.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a7e0383ff6c23d7fc33070066a4abaa3

Here's a version that might be appropriate for SQL Server specifically. It does separate searches for next lower and next higher values. Depending on the indexing it could be the more efficient approach.

```
/* more complicated but possibly a better plan */
update c
set PostalCode = case when abs(Code - Code1) <= abs(Code - Code2)
                      then Code1 else coalesce(Code2, Code1) end /* ties go low */
from Clients c
    cross apply (values (cast(PostalCode as int))) z0(Code) cross apply (
    select min(PostalCode), cast(min(PostalCode) as int) from Zips z
    where z.PostalCode > c.PostalCode
) z1(PostalCode1, Code1) cross apply (
    select max(PostalCode), cast(min(PostalCode) as int) from Zips z
    where z.PostalCode < c.PostalCode
) z2(PostalCode2, Code2)
where not exists (
    select 1 from Zips z where z.PostalCode = c.PostalCode
);
```

Comment: Compare query costs here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2558f6cebcb325335f60bc4a93d9c7ea

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the work. When a value is entered in the "Clients" table, for example "97324", the value returned is "null" when it should be "94016"

Comment: @zacalarra Did you use the first version where it was requiring the first two characters of the zip code to match? I didn't expect gaps that big but if it's not slow you can comment out the whole `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
with cte as(
Select A.Postal_Code As UpdateTo,B.Postal_Code As ToBeUpdated, 
Row_Number() Over (Partition By B.Postal_Code Order By Abs(A.Postal_Code-B.Postal_Code)) as rn
From Postals A , Clients B 
)

Update Clients C Set C.Postal_Code = (Select D.UpdateTo From cte D 
                                      where C.Postal_Code=D.ToBeUpdated and D.rn=1);
select * from Clients
```

See a demo from *[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tNYqTQEnwN7dmziRGx1JHM/0)*.